# app/mocks.ts(1,2): error TS1109: Expression expected

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm learning Angular and after some time I've run into this problem with a **mocks.ts** file:

1) **mocks.ts** looks like this:

```
@import { Races } from './races';

export const RACES: Races[] = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Daytona Thunderdome",
    "date": new Date('2512-01-04T14:00:00'),
    "about": "Race through the ruins of an ancient Florida battle arena.",
    "entryFee": 3200,
    "isRacing": false
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "San Francisco Ruins",
    "date": new Date('2512-07-03T20:00:00'),
    "about": "Drift down the streets of a city almost sunk under the ocean.",
    "entryFee": 4700,
    "isRacing": true
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "New York City Skyline",
    "date": new Date('2512-07-12T21:00:00'),
    "about": "Fly between buildings in the electronic sky.",
    "entryFee": 4300,
    "isRacing": true
  }];
```

2)I'm importing **Races** from races.ts file, which looks like this:

```
  export class Races {
    "id": number;
    "name": string;
    "date": string;
    "about": string;
    "entryFee": number;
    "isRacing": boolean;
}
```

3) And than I'm importing **RACES** to **races.component.ts**, which looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Races } from './races';
import { RACES } from './mocks';

@Component({
    selector: 'races',
    templateUrl: 'app/races.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/races.component.css']
})
export class RacesComponent {
  races: Races[];
  cash = 10000;
  ngOnInit() {
      this.races = RACES;
  };
  // Write your function here
  totalCost() {
      var sum = 0;
      for(let race of this.races) {
          if(race.isRacing) {
              sum += race.entryFee;
          }
      }
      return sum;
  };
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Get rid of `@` in the import statement in the *mocks.ts*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fixed it, but got another Error after this. Will be working on that one right now )